# Why is rust-analyzer not finding dependencies in workspace member?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-cargo, rust-analyzer

I have a cargo workspace with one library `./raytracing` and one binary `./cli`. The two workspace members have different dependencies.

./raytracing/Cargo.toml:

```ini
[package]
name = "raytracer"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
rand = "0.8.5"
```

./cli/Cargo.toml:

```ini
[package]
name = "cli"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
raytracer = {path = "../raytracer"}
rand = "0.8.5"
rand_xorshift = "0.3.0"
```

Parent directory Cargo.toml (./Cargo.toml)

```ini
[package]
edition = "2021"
name = "raytracing"
version = "0.1.0"

[workspace]
members = [
    "raytracer",
    "cli",
]

[[bin]]
path = "cli/src/main.rs"
name = "cli"
```

Compiling both the raytracer and cli packages using cargo build -p works, however in VSCode rust-analyzer complains about my dependencies in the ./cli package when I import them in main.rs:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAk28.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current setup you actually have two binaries compiled from the same source file: one from from `./cli/Cargo.toml`, and one from `./Cargo.toml`. `./Cargo.toml` doesn't declare any `[dependencies]` so of course you're getting an error when trying to compile a binary form that. You haven't explained what you're trying to achieve, so I can't tell you the correct way to fix this problem. Generally, there's two things you can do:

- Make the root package [virtual](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/workspaces.html#virtual-manifest) by deleting everything from `./Cargo.toml` except the `[workspace]` section. (normal)
- Ditch the `./cli/Cargo.toml` and move its `[dependencies]` section to `./Cargo.toml`. (bit weird)

Comment: Making the root package virtual was the way to go. Thanks.